# Add link button between inline

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to add a button, that link to another place of the app, between an inline in the admin interface.

I mean, after the *main* class and before the inline class.

Comment: Didn't understand what you want. Can you post some code or some screenshot on what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use custom changeform template:

See https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html

And override:

```
{% block after_field_sets %}
    <your button goes here>
{% endblock %}
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Comment: The button is shown before the inline as I wanted but it's shown in its own admin interface too which it's not desired.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by its  `own admin interface`? Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: I see the button in every model page of the admin interface not just in the page of the inline